# Python 3 strange division

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding, integer-division, largenumber

About half an hour thinking "what am i doing wrong!?" on the 5-lines code.. because Python3 is somehow rounding big integers. Anyone know why there is a problem such:

Python2:

```
int(6366805760909027985741435139224001        # This is 7**40.
    / 7) == 909543680129861140820205019889143 # 7**39
```

Python3:

```
int(6366805760909027985741435139224001 
    / 7) == 909543680129861204865300750663680 # I have no idea what this is.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python 3 is not "rounding big integers". What it does is that it will return a float after division. Hence, in Python 2:

```
>>> 4/2
2
```

while in Python 3:

```
>>> 4/2
2.0
```

The reason for this is simple. In Python 2, `/` being integer division when you use integers have some surprising results:

```
>>> 5/2
2
```

Ooops. In Python 3 this is fixed:

```
>>> 5/2
2.5
```

This means that in Python 3, your division returns a float:

```
>>> 6366805760909027985741435139224001/7
9.095436801298612e+32
```

This float has less accuracy than the digits you need. 
You then convert this to an integer with `int()`, and you get a number you don't expect.

You should instead use integer division (in both Python 2 and Python 3):

```
>>> 6366805760909027985741435139224001//7
909543680129861140820205019889143L
```

(The trailing L means it's a long integer, in Python 3 the long and the normal integer is merged, so there is no trailing L).

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3 `/` is floating point division so it may not treat your arguments like integers. Use

```
//
```

to do integer division in Python 3.

Comment: you could also use `//` in Python 2 i.e., the same source could be used on Python 2 and 3. `(7**40 // 7) == 7**39`. `from __future__ import division` enables Python 3 behaviour for `/` on Python 2.