# Difference in long int division in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, long-integer, division, integer-division

I came across a bizarre situation while doing some large number division in python.

```
int(1012337203685477580 / 2) = 506168601842738816
```

and

```
int(1012337203685477580 >> 1) = 506168601842738790
```

Why is there a difference between the two approaches? int() appears to be at the least int64 because int(2^63 - 1) and 2^63 - 1 are the same values.

Comment: Why did you call `int`? Take those calls out; they're hiding the source of the problem.

Comment: Also, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20810729

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, `/` is true division, so you will get a floating point result, and all the accuracy problems that entails. Use `//` for integer division instead:

```
>>> 1012337203685477580 / 2
5.061686018427388e+17
>>> 1012337203685477580 // 2
506168601842738790
>>> 1012337203685477580 >> 1
506168601842738790
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the answer. It was driving me nuts! :)